# Верстка письма под ms outlook

Tags: html, css

Похоже, аутлук добавляет таблицам отступы слева и справа, так как есть таблицы `290рх + 20рх + 290рх` и они не влазят в общую таблицу шириной `600рх`.
Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой и знает как обнулить отступы или дело вовсе не в них...

Answer (score 0):

Каждой добавляемой таблице при вёрстке Email-писем добавляйте эти атрибуты

`<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0">`

Это убережет Вас от проблем с подставляемыми сервисами отступами.

Comment: да, спасибо, это все есть. нашел инфу что именно для аутлука нужно писать не margin а Margin